# Maker - checker concept in Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to add Maker/Checker concept in my application. Previously it is manage by making to identical table of a single domain. For example,If there is Customer domain then customers_main and customers_temp are the two tables which is structurally identically.So when new customer is created it goes to customers_temp table and wait for approval.Once it is approved by higher level user then it removes from customers_temp table and goes to customers_main table. So in short if there is modification it goes to customer_temp table and other user can't see change until it is verified by authorised user.

In my project I'm using Java EE 6 with JPA2 so wondering is there any better way to do it with Java ?

Comment: I don't believe there is anything special in JPA to support this, if that's what you're asking.  Just create a transaction, insert into customers_main, delete from customer_temp, commit the transaction.  Pretty much just like any other database interaction.

Comment: You could probably use inheritance so that you don't have to define all the fields on two separate classes...

Comment: till now Iam using Inheritance just want to know if there is better way to do it then